# Array slicing in C

Tags: c, arrays

In Python, if I wanted to assign the vector `x=(1,2)` to the first two elements of `y=(0,0,0,0)`, I would do something like `y[:1] = x`.  Is there an equivalent in C to assign a `double x[2]={1.,2.}` to the first two elements of an available `double y[4] = {0.,0.,0.,0.}`? Or will I have to loop?

Comment: There are libraries that provide this kind of functionality however nothing is built into the C programming language for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying a subset of an array into another array / array slicing in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618342/copying-a-subset-of-an-array-into-another-array-array-slicing-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x[2] = {1., 2.};
    double y[4] = {0., 0., 0., 0.};

    memcpy(y, x, 2 * sizeof(*x));
              /* ^ 2 elements of size -> sizeof(double) */

    return 0;
}
```

instead of writing `sizeof(double)` which is ok, i did `sizeof(*x)` because if I change the type of `x` I wouldn't need to fix the `memcpy`, but i would also have to change the type of `y` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, how can I control which two indices of y get assigned to with this?

Comment: @conjectures You can use `y+1` to start writing from the address of `y[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that passes in the pointer or array, an offset, and a length. The function then allocates space to a new pointer with malloc() and does a memcpy() operation or loop-and-copy, although memcpy() is probably better. The new pointer is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the function `memcpy`. But you have to be careful about data types. You can also copy data of one type to another. Again as I said, you need to be careful. Otherwise it may generate garbage value.

And second option is looping as mentioned in question.

Comment: This question is tagged as C, which I believe does not support classes or operator overloading.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. A bit more low-level than your python method but welcome to C where sooner or later everything is block of raw memory to be shunted around!

The macro arraycopy applies some size checking.
The function arraycopyunchecked is fairly raw.

The functions are overlap safe. Under the hood they use `memcopy(,,)` which may be slower but won't have surprise results if unexpected aliasing results in overlapping arrrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //includes mempcy. I know! I know!

#define arraycopy(dest,doffset,source,soffset,count) arraycopy_((dest),(doffset),(source),(soffset),(count),sizeof(*(dest)),sizeof(*(source)))

int  arraycopy_(void*const dest,const size_t doffset,const void*const source, const size_t soffset,const size_t count,const size_t size,const size_t sizecheck){ 
    if(size!=sizecheck){
        return 1;//Incompatible types.
    }
    memcopy(((char*)dest)+doffset*size,((const char*)source)+soffset*size,count*size);
    return 0;
}

int  arraycopyunchecked(void*const dest,const size_t doffset,const void*const source, const size_t soffset,const size_t count,const size_t size){ 
    memcopy(((char*)dest)+doffset*size,((const char*)source)+soffset*size,count*size);
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {

    int errors=0;

    double dest[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double source[]={1.0,2.0};

    arraycopy(dest,0,source,0,2);

    if(dest[0]!=1.0){
        ++errors;
    }

    if(dest[1]!=2.0){
        ++errors;
    }   

    if(dest[2]!=0.0){
        ++errors;
    }   

    arraycopy(dest,1,source,0,2);

    if(dest[0]!=1.0){
        ++errors;
    }

    if(dest[1]!=1.0){
        ++errors;
    }   

    if(dest[2]!=2.0){
        ++errors;
    }   


    if(errors!=0){
        printf("Errors - %d\n",errors);
    }else{
        printf("SUCCESS");
    }

    double dest1[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double source1[]={1.0,2.0,3.0};

    arraycopy(dest1,2,source1,1,2);

    if(dest[2]!=2.0){
        ++errors;
    }

    if(dest[3]!=3.0){
        ++errors;
    }

   return errors==0?EXIT_SUCCESS:EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```