# Pass in part of an array as function argument

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array `int arr[5] = {10, 2, 3, 5, 1}`, and I want to pass in the last 4 elements (basically from index 1 to index4) into an argument as an array (so: `[2, 3, 5, 1]`). Is there a way to do this very simply (like how in Ruby you would be able to do arr[1..4]), or would I have to use a for loop?

Comment: Why not pass the array, starting and end index of the subarray you want as argument to that function.

Comment: This question might help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646512/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-c

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618342/copying-a-subset-of-an-array-into-another-array-array-slicing-in-c

Comment: `&arr[1]` does the job — as long as you don't want to pass a copy (the function isn't going to modify the array, or it doesn't matter if it does).  If you want to copy, you have to do the copying manually.

Comment: You can't pass arrays as function arguments in C. Instead, you can pass the address of the initial element and the size as separate arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually increment the pointer by 1:

```
your_function(arr + 1)
```

Pointer arithmetic in C implicitly accounts for the size of the elements, so adding 1 will actually add `1 * sizeof(int)`

For a closer analogue to array slicing from other languages, try this function:

```
int *slice_array(int *array, int start, int end) {
    int numElements = (end - start + 1)
    int numBytes = sizeof(int) * numElements;

    int *slice = malloc(numBytes);
    memcpy(slice, array + start, numBytes)

    return slice;
}
```

It makes a slice of the array between the given start and end indices. Remember to `free()` the slice once you're done with it!

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

Given you current code:

```
int arr[5] = {10, 2, 3, 5, 1};
```

You can duplicate the range 1..4 by:

```
int arr_dup[4];
memcpy(arr_dup,arr+1,sizeof(int)*4);
```

Remember that your function definition should be a pointer, example:

```
void a_function(int *arr_arg); //Call via a_function(arr_dup);
```

### Explanation

Arrays in c implemented as pointers (aka variables that hold memory addresses).

If you do arithmetic on the pointer, it will advance to the respective element. Example:

```
ptr + 1 //Next Element
ptr - 1 //Previous Element
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void my_function(int arr_size, int *arr)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
      printf("[%d]:%d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int arr[] = { 10, 2, 3, 5, 1 };
  (void)my_function(4, &arr[1]); /* TODO > use more flexible indexing */
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using old-style pre-ANSI function definitions? Use prototypes; `void my_function(int arr_size, int *arr)`, `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Explain why there is an appreciable difference. No compiler nor standard was mentioned, so I picked a historical style. I work in older code bases and have come to like this style of function definition due to the ease of documenting parameters. Additionally, why would I use prototypes for something so simple?

Comment: Old-style function declarations and definitions have been obsolescent since 1989. Prototypes were added to the language because old-style declarations do not let the compiler check the correctness of calls. You could write `my_function("foo", 12.3, 42, NULL)` and the compiler wouldn't complain (but it would probably blow up at run time).

Comment: I hadn't tried calling my functions incorrectly, heh. Updated the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `memcpy`,`memcpy` can copy data byte to byte.In memmory,our data is binary,so even `int` is 4 bytes,we can copy it byte to byte.

---

```
int dst[4];
memcpy(dst,&arr[1],size(int) * 4);
```